# How do I find the len() of multiple strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the len() of multiple strings.

```
current_year = input ("What year is it?")

current_year = int(current_year)

birth_year = input ("What year were you born in?")

birth_year = str(birth_year)

if len(birth_year) != 4:
    print ("Please make your year of birth 4 digits long.")
else:
    birth_year = int(birth_year)
    print("You are " + str(current_year  -  birth_year) + " years old.")
```

I would like to include the len() of birth_year.

Comment: "Include" where?

Comment: what actually have you tried so far? You seem familiar with the `len` function, have you tried using that against hte string representing the year?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I would like to find the len() of current_year. And I have tried to put a comma after the birth_year. For example:                                                                             
       if len(birth_year, current_year) != 4

Comment: What is wrong with `len(str(current_year))` ?

Comment: @IMCoins Can you please clarify? I do not believe that I have included the code that you have just mentioned.

Comment: `import datetime` and then do `current_year = datetime.now().year`. this will ensure it's valid integer rather than leaving it up to the user to input the correct format.

Comment: Otherwise, if you need to validate multiple inputs, you'd be best to compartmentalize the input into its own function that includes the validation/etc.

Comment: But then you also need to validate that they gave you a numeric input, and not some nonsense like "abcd" or "198H", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `elif` statement to check the current year input.

```
current_year = input ("What year is it?")    
birth_year = input ("What year were you born in?")

if len(birth_year) != 4:
    print ("Please make your year of birth 4 digits long.")
elif len(current_year) != 4:
    print ("Please make the current year 4 digits long.")
else:
    birth_year = int(birth_year)
    current_year = int(current_year)
    print("You are " + str(current_year  -  birth_year) + " years old.")
```

There's no need for `birth_year = str(birth_year)`, since `input()` always returns a string.

You should probably include `try/except` code around the calls to `int()`, so you can print an error if they enter a year that isn't actually a number.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get what you want that is somewhat more dynamic.  With this basic function, if a user inputs an inappropriate string, they will be asked to retry.  You could even add a line to check if the year was after the current year.

Note that there is a loop in here with an exit that doesn't have a constraint.  If you were going to implement this, I'd add a counter as well which would kill the process to prevent infinite loops.

```
def get_year(input_string):

    # Set loop control Variable
    err = True

    # while loop control variable = true
    while err == True:

        # get input
        input_year = input(input_string + '  ')

        # Ensure format is correct        
        try:

            # Check length
            if len(input_year) == 4:

                # Check Data type
                input_year = int(input_year)

                # if everything works, exit loop by changing variable
                err = False

        # if there was an error, re-enter the loop
        except:

            pass

    # return integer version of input for math
    return input_year

# set variables = function output
birth_year = get_year('What year were you born? Please use a YYYY format!\n')
current_year = get_year('What is the current year? Please use a YYYY format!\n')

# print output displaying age
print("You are " + str(current_year  -  birth_year) + " years old.")
```